# How do I calculate a percentage based on the output of a Java 8 Stream filter

Tags: java, java-8, lambda

I want to take a List of jobs (called resultStream) and calculate the percentage of jobs that were completed fully.

```
public class Job {
    private Date date;
    private String success;

    // Getter and setter and constructor.
}
```

The list contains the following:

```
new Job("TODAY", "YES");
new Job("TODAY", "YES");
new Job("YESTERDAY", "YES");
new Job("TODAY", "NO");
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
resultStream.stream().parallel().filter(result -> {
   if ("YES".contains(result.getSuccess())) {
       return true;         
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}).collect(groupingBy(Job::getDate, HashMap::new, counting()));
```

This returns me a HashMap(Date, Long) with the following:
    TODAY, 2
    YESTERDAY, 1

I actually want the following result:
    TODAY, 66%
    YESTERDAY, 100%

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW your filter should actually say `result -> "YES".contains(result.getSuccess())`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Average as double can be done as so:

```
public static void main(final String... args) {
    final List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
    jobs.add(new Job(LocalDate.now(), "YES"));
    jobs.add(new Job(LocalDate.now(), "NO"));
    jobs.add(new Job(LocalDate.now(), "YES"));
    jobs.add(new Job(LocalDate.now()
            .minusDays(1), "YES"));

    final Map<LocalDate, Double> result = jobs.stream()
        .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Job::getDate,
                            Collectors.mapping(Job::getSuccess, Collectors.averagingDouble(success -> {
                                return "YES".equals(success) ? 1 : 0;
                            }))));

    // result = {2014-07-20=1.0, 2014-07-21=0.6666666666666666}
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

As strings:

```
public static void main(final String... args) {
    final List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
    jobs.add(new Job(LocalDate.now(), "YES"));
    jobs.add(new Job(LocalDate.now(), "NO"));
    jobs.add(new Job(LocalDate.now(), "YES"));
    jobs.add(new Job(LocalDate.now()
            .minusDays(1), "YES"));

    final Map<LocalDate, String> result = jobs.stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Job::getDate,
                            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                    Collectors.mapping(Job::getSuccess, Collectors.averagingDouble(success -> {
                                        return "YES".equals(success) ? 1 : 0;
                                    })), avg -> String.format("%,.0f%%", avg * 100))));
    // result = {2014-07-20=100%, 2014-07-21=67%}
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: +1 looks good to me. Averaging an [indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)  is the way to go with these kinds of booleans.

Comment: +1, I was hoping someone would prove me wrong :) BTW you can replace the lambda block with just the expression inside `averagingDouble`.

Comment: Does this code compile for you? I get an error in IntelliJ saying "avg" is an object and the operator "*" can not be applied to avg.

Comment: Spot on. It was an issue with my IntelliJ version. Latest version 13.1.4 fixes the issue.